# Using ASP.NET Application Account Login for Hosted Websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

Visual Studio 2010 has a way to create a new website.

I have done that with 4 different websites, all are hosted remotely on Godaddy, and they all run fine.

All of these sites come with a default Microsoft login link:

[image: Microsoft Login]

The link goes to documentation on MSDN, but that documentation covers everything in depth. I'm not a DBA, and I have never figured out how to get one of my websites to use this feature.

In the past, I have either deleted those links or set them so they were not displayed.

Now, I'd like to learn what is required to getting them to working - just something basic.

I went there and created a new, blank Microsoft SQL database. The tables are not setup, though. That may be all I need!

Looking at the default settings in the web.config file, it looks like I can simply edit the connection string to be what I need.

Microsoft posts a link in their code, but I must confess that I really don't know what I'm looking **for**, so it is hard to tell when I am looking at the **solution**.

[image: web.config]

### For a hosted website (like GoDaddy), does anyone know how to get the database setup?

I'm looking for a spoon fed, Step-By-Step, "How To" for dummies like me that spend most of their time developing Windows Forms.

Comment: @mason, I put that there in case it is necessary, so others know that I do not have it.

Comment: Done! I left the `forms-authentication` tag. Is that part still reliant?

Comment: I'd leave that one, as people looking at forms authentication tag will know about the various membership providers that work with it.

Answer (score 2):

You are using ASP.Net - **Legacy SQL Membership Provide**r. It has been deprecated long time ago.

[ASP.Net Identity 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx) is new, but it requires .Net 4.5

Closest to Legacy Membership Provider is [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx).

*Link from the 2nd picture is for web.config in general. It doesn't include any information about Membership Provider.*

Comment: .Net 4.0 is as high as my hosting service allows. Is there a script or anything I can run on the new database I created that configures the database to work with this **SQL Membership Provider**?

Comment: If you want to use SQL Membership Provider, you need to run **aspnet_regsql.exe** which will create schema and store procedures for you. Look at [this](http://www.shiningstar.net/ASPNet_Articles/SqlMembershipProvider.aspx) post.

Comment: I see this command: `aspnet_regsql -S (local) -E -A m` ...but I don't understand how to run that for a hosted website like Godaddy.

Comment: Actually, the keywords **aspnet_regsql** and **godaddy** appear to be pulling up a lot of hits. Investigating now...

Comment: Normally, I run **aspnet_regsql** on local SQL Server. Then I generate a script, and run it on remote server.

Comment: @jp2code A lot of hosting providers actually support .NET 4.5, but since .NET 4.5 is still considered .NET 4.0 by IIS, it confuses people into thinking they don't support 4.5. You should make a simple .NET 4.5 site with VS 2013 and see if it works.